# Is the nofollow attribute present in reddit links?

Tags: seo, links, nofollow, social-media

All SEO articles I've read on this subject claim that reddit links are nofollow.  I am not questioning that information, but I would like to know how these folks are able to verify that reddit links are in fact nofollow.

Using the "inspect element" function in Chrome while logged into reddit, I have clicked on a reddit link and found the following:

```
<a class="title may-blank loggedin " href=
"/r/SEO/comments/2kg0mn/do_reddit_links_count_as_backlinks_or_are_they/" tabindex="1">
Do Reddit links count as backlinks? Or are they no-follow?</a>
```

Inspecting the same element while logged out, I see the following:

```
<a class="title may-blank " href=
"/r/SEO/comments/2kg0mn/do_reddit_links_count_as_backlinks_or_are_they/" tabindex="1">
Do Reddit links count as backlinks? Or are they no-follow?</a>
```

I don't see the  `nofollow` atribute in either case.  Is it hidden in the CSS somewhere?  If so, where exactly?

Comment: Your example shows an _internal_ link, which is less likely to be nofollow anyway. But the presence of a `nofollow` attribute isn't necessarily the only thing that can determine whether a link is effectively nofollow or not. It could simply be blocked by robots.txt

Answer (score 2):

Reddit links don't carry the `nofollow` link relationship unless they are from a users page on the network. In the examples you provide, they are followed links.

There is no CSS or Javascript override or just served for Googlebot making publicly shared URL's `nofollow`. I fetched a page as Googlebot to confirm this also.

You can see an example of which links are followed and which are nofollowed from analysing [this page](https://www.reddit.com/top/?sort=top&t=year) over [at Ahrefs](https://ahrefs.com/site-explorer/referring/domains/exact/all/all/1/backlinks_dofollow_desc?target=http%3A%2F%2Fshare.gifyoutube.com%2Fm6807g.gif).